# Why is flask not able to import the config string

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I am trying to use flask and celery together. Currently I have a project structure like so:

```
+-Project_root
    |-celeryconfig.py
    |-config.py
    |
    +-flask_react_app
      |-__init__.py
      |-wsgi.py
      |-wsgi_aux.py
      |-task.py
      |-flask_react_app.py
```

When I run the command `celery worker --app flask_react_app` I get the error:

```
ImportError: import_string() failed for 'config.DevelopmentConfig'. Possible reasons are:

- missing __init__.py in a package;
- package or module path not included in sys.path;
- duplicated package or module name taking precedence in sys.path;
- missing module, class, function or variable;

Debugged import:

- 'config' not found.
```

my config.py is simply:

```
import os


class Config:
    DEBUG = False
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
    SOCKETIO_MESSAGE_QUEUE = os.environ['CELERY_BROKER_URL']
    CELERY_CONFIG = {}


class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = True


class ProductionConfig(Config):
    pass


class TestingConfig(Config):
    TESTING = True
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite://'
    CELERY_CONFIG = {'CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER': True}
```

I can't understand why the flask app is not able to find the config, as it is an environment variable with a simple string `'config.DevelopmentConfig'`

I have linked the relative branch in my project to reduce the amount of code in this question.
[https://github.com/jbevan4/flask_react_app/tree/flask_socketio_sql_alchemy_intergation](https://github.com/jbevan4/flask_react_app/tree/flask_socketio_sql_alchemy_intergation%20here)

Comment: Not familiar with celery...but aren't you missing a `__init__.py` file inside Project_root?

Comment: The project root shouldn't have one form the examples I've seen.